# Help with Regex - Wordpress (search-regex)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, pcre

My first attempt using RE has me stuck.  I'm using Regex on a Wordpress website via the [Search-Regex Plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/) and need to match on a specific " buried within a bunch of html code.  HTML example:

```
provide brand-strengthening efforts for the 10-school conference.&#0160; </p>
<p>
   <a href="http://www.learfield.com/oldblog/.a/6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c-pi">
   <img alt="MOvalleyConf500" 
        border="0" 
        class="at-xid-6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c"
        src="http://www.learfield.com/oldblog/.a/6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c-800wi" 
        style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px; width: 502px; height: 384px;"             
        title="MOvalleyConf500" />
   </a>
</p>
<p>The photo above
```

In the above example, there are three targets

```
6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c-pi"
6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c"
6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c-800wi"
```

The Regex I'm using is `/6a00d834.*?"/` it locates them, however I only want to match on the ending `"` and not the entire string.  These are images that are missing their file extension, so I need to replace the ending " with .jpg"  I understand the replacement part of the expression, it's the initial matching I'm having trouble with.

I have a bunch of these (221), all the targets all begin with `6a00d834` then some random alphanumeric ending with a `"`

Appreciate any insight. Thanks.

**Edit added from OP's comment**: Actually it's on a Wordpress site using a plugin (REGEX) to query and replace data within SQL. I can use any Perl compatible regex. (Note from editor - depending on the plugin, this is most likely not actually using Perl but PHP's implementation of PCRE.)

Comment: What exactly do you want from that data?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match and extract?

Comment: And what language do you want it for?

Comment: Perl - my bad earlier.  Actually it's on a Wordpress site using a plugin (REGEX) to query and replace data within SQL.  I can use any perl compatible regex.  Thus far everyone's help has either returned the same results as my /6a00d834.*?"/ (matching the entire 6a00d8345233fa69e201157155a6fc970c" or nothing at all).  Once again, I appreciate everyone help here.

Comment: @Phil: Is this the plugin? http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/ If so, that's using PHP to drive the regular expression, so it's PHP's PCRE not pure Perl. Also, can you put this information and a link to the plugin in the question?

Comment: @Phil: so many people seem to be confused about what's going on here, that I did the edit myself for the moment. Feel free to clean it up as you see fit. I don't mean to highjack your question, but it's very unclear frankly.

Comment: Thanks Telemachus, sorry to be so unclear, I've edited the question yet again in hopes of clearly explaining what I'm attempting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String replacement can be done along with the matching. Since you're using PHP, use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/(6a00d834.*?)(\")/", "\\1.jpg\\2", $oldstring)
```

This breaks the match into two groups, and then inserts '.jpg' between them.

For the [wordpress regex plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/screenshots/), use /(6a00d834.*?)(")/ for the match string, and then use \1.jpg\2 for the replacement string.

Comment: That did it. Thanks Michael.  Sorry the initial question was so unclear.  I'll try to be more specific next time.

Community: thanks so much for your assistance.  You guys are great!

Comment: Michael was able to make sense of this and provide the solution.  Thanks to all, but especially Michael for sticking it out!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work?

```
/(6a00d834.*?)"/
```

**Edit:** You said in one of your comments you wanted to replace the `"` with `.jpg"`; in that case this regexp would probably work:

```
/6a00d834.*?(")/
```

However, the best thing to do is probably to use the first regexp I provided, and use a replacement string that looks like this:

```
'\\1.jpg"'
```

Of course, `\\1` has to be replaced with whatever you particular regexp engine uses for backreferences.

Comment: @Michael: I probably nested it incorrectly. Is it correct now?

Comment: thanks guys, /(6a00d834.*?)"/ is matching the same as /6a00d834.*?"/ for me.  In the three example string I posted, I only was to hit on the ending "  These are image links that are missing their extension, so I want to replace the " with .jpg"  hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: @Phil: replacing the `"` feels kind of backwards; try appending `.jpg` the match of the first result of the first regexp I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not entirely clear, but perhaps you mean:

```
/6a00d834[^"]*"/
```

(That is: match 6a00d834 followed by zero or more characters that are not a " followed by a ")

Alternatively, if it is available in the regex engine you are using, you can use a non-greedy specifier to limit the '*' meta-character.  Keep in mind that any question about regex's is dependent on the engine you are using.  For example:

```
$ cat input
6a00384foo" more"
$ perl -ne '/(6a00384[^"]*")/; print "$1\n"' input
6a00384foo"
$ perl -ne '/(6a00384.*?")/; print "$1\n"' input
6a00384foo"
$ sed 's/\(6a00384[^"]*"\).*/\1/' input
6a00384foo"
$ sed 's/\(6a00384.*?"\).*/\1/' input
6a00384foo" more"
```

Notice that the '?' does not serve as a non-greedy specifier in sed.

Comment: the non-greedy regex Phil is using already accomplishes this.  That's the '*?' part of the regex.

Comment: Using ? to indicate non-greedy is perl specific.  Using [^"] is more general.

Comment: Sometimes portability is more important.  Response edited to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a group operator?

```
/6a00d834.*?(")/
```

Then, depending on your regex API, you can pull out just what is matched in the parens.

**Edit**

Ah, you want to do string replacement.  I'll guess you're using Perl.   Try this:

```
s/(6a00d834.*?)(")/\1.jpg\2/
```

Comment: This is kind of redundant though, since you'd always get a double qoute from that grouping.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that was what he wanted: 'however I only want to match on the end " and not the entire target string.'

Comment: All due respect, but the OP may not be the best judge of what he _really_ wants, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to extract everything after `6a00d834` up to the first following `"`. So try this:

```
/6a00d834([^"]*)"/
```

The match of first grouping will than be the string you are looking for.

Comment: I only wanting to extract the " at the end of a string that begins with 6a00d834<some unknow number of alphanumerics>"

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: to replace the " with .jpg"  the are image links that are mising the file extension

Comment: Why didn’t you say that in the first place? And what language do you use?

Comment: Phil is already using a non-greedy match, so to get this closer to his regex it would be: /6a00d834(.*?)"/