# URL regex search and replace on MySQL (in WordPress)

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin, replace

I have a WordPress blog with numerous URL's I wish to replace from this:

> http://www.oldwebsite.co.il/name/***.asp

To this:

> http://www.newwebsite.com/?p=***

**For example**, from this:

> http://oldwebsite.co.il/name/65971.asp

To this:

> http://www.newwebsite.com/?p=65971

I believe the following plugin:
http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/
 will do the trick with regex, but I am looking for the correct regex to use here.

I found [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216600/help-with-regex-wordpress-search-regex) that has a similar task, but since I am not too apt with regex, I was hoping for help so I don't mess anything up.

Thanks,

Tal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the regular expression:

```
http://oldwebsite\.co\.il/name/(\d+)\.asp
```

and replace with:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/?p=$1
```

In PHP:

```
$after = preg_replace('%http://oldwebsite\.co\.il/name/(\d+)\.asp%', 'http://www.newwebsite.com/?p=$1', $before);
```

Comment: you have to escape 'backslashes and forwardslashes' or wrap your pattern in |pattern-goes-here| using || you dont have to escape characters.

Comment: My PHP code uses % signs to delimit the regex so I don't have to escape forward slashes.  Using | to delimit the regex is a bad idea because | is a regex metacharacter.